# What was the utility of Shelley Island?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, supergirl-2015

On *Supergirl*, Shelley Island shows up in the fourth season.

Per the [Wiki article](https://arrow.fandom.com/wiki/Shelley_Island):

> It was converted into an interplanetary port of entry by President
>   Marsdin for alien immigrants, but was shut down and abandoned after
>   Marsdin's resignation.

The symbolism is obvious: a monument resembling the Statue of Liberty, a purpose and name similar to Ellis Island.

However, Ellis Island was used for immigration processing because large numbers of immigrants were coming by boat to New York City from Europe: perhaps even the majority, given a limited number of boat routes. On the other hand, extraterrestrials aren't necessarily aiming for National City, and mostly arrive by spaceship (and thus won't be coming by water). In fact, unless their spaceship landed on the island or in the water, they'd have to be transported out there by boat. In-universe, what's the utility of Shelley Island?

Comment: Really, it's "President Marsdin"? I assumed it was spelled "Marston", a hat tip to William Moulton Marston, the creator of Wonder Woman.

Comment: @VBartilucci Spelling notwithstanding, is there any reason _not_ to think there is such a connection? Her first name is Olivia, which reminds us of Olive Byrne. Both Byrne and Marston were instrumental in the creation of Wonder Woman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything about the establishment would have to be guesswork, but we could make a few assumptions.

**The island almost certainly has a landing platform for ships** - We didn't see it cause it wasn't needed (and it would cost money), but if it's an entry point for aliens, there would need to be a place to land their ships. Said landing platform could also be used by the DEO or any other group for transporting incoming aliens who landed elsewhere.

**A single (or a small number) location for processing of aliens makes sense** - There may presumably be a similar base on the opposite coast, but since the number of alien immigrants is enough to be a national issue, one has to assume it's not as many as any group of terrestrial immigrants. It's fair to guess that like the real world, there's a lot of immigrants in larger cities, but not as many in small towns.

**Having alien ships land at a pre-arranged location makes sense for security** - If incoming ships are told via some sort of broadcast signal to land at coordinates ABC , it would be easier to identify any ships that land elsewhere as hostile, or at the very least trying to do something sneaky.  Having ships land near the coast also makes sense, as a base located, say, in the desert, while safe due to its remoteness, would require said ship traveling many miles into US Airspace, which is certainly a security risk.